# Why text does not show in firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to save text entered in the text field on my Web Page.

This is my code for saving data

```
function btnLogin(){
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
       if(user){
        var time = new Date();
         var options = {
         weekday: "long", 
         month: "long",
         day:  "2-digit",
         year: "numeric",

    };

  var message = $("#d").val(); 

  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid = userId.uid;
    var myref = firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).child('Blogs');


    var blogInformation =
    {
        "desc": message,
        "time": time.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true}),
        "date": time.toLocaleDateString('en-US',options),
        "counter": 100000000 - counter
    }

    var newPostRef = myref.push();
    newPostRef.set(blogInformation, function(err){
        if(err){
            $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
            $("#result").html(err.message);
        }else{
            $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-success");
            $("#result").html("Blog has been added successfully.");

            window.open("","_self");
        }
    });

          }

      });


       resetForm();

    }
```

But when I save it to firebase the text does not show.
The image below is a screenshot of my firebase.
I hope my question is clear.
Can anyone help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73RSS.png)

This is my HTML

```
<div class="container text-center">
     <form id="main-form">
          <div class="form-group">
             <textarea id="d" type="text" rows="5" placeholder="Description..." class="form-control" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                 <button id="save-blog" type="button" style="width: 150px; height: 60px;" class="btn btn-light bg-light text-dark" onclick="btnLogin()">PUBLISH</button>
          </div>
     </form>

     <div id="result">

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a html  input, select or textarea, with a value and id=d;

```
<input value='something' id='d' />
```

Be sure message has a value:

```
var message = $("#d").val(); 
console.log(message);
```

Also, learn about variable hoisting, function scope, const, and let.

Let me know if this help

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have the id set as id = "d", but it does not work

Comment: and also the console does not show any error message

Comment: Consider  posting your HTML.   What kind of element has id d?  Does it have a value?  (user typed into it?)
Does console.log(message) show up in the console?  If not you have an empty message and that is why it is not saved to firebase.

Comment: ok I have posted my html below can please see and let me know what am i doing wrong and also the  console.log(message) nothing shows. Thank you again

Comment: yes  but only when the test is entered the first time in the textarea, i enter in the textarea the second time it saves, so I am not sure what is going on

Comment: When debugging, isolate the problem.  Add console.log throughout the code will help you do this.  It seems like all data sent to firebase IS saved.  Now we need to figure out why .val() does not return a value.

Comment: Stuck?  Try something different, substitute input for textarea, set default text, confirm text is NOT getting cleared during you click/submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this code. JavaScript needs to identify that textfield value changes.

```
$('#d').change(function () {
  var d = $("#d").val();
  if (d != '') {
      console.log(d);
  }
});
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, using the above code show the text in the console but does not save to firebase

Comment: Actually when I put the text in the textarea the first time it does not work but in the second time it works

Comment: You mean other time and date values are saved successfully but desc value is not saved?

Comment: @Ron Please elaborate on first time does not work, second time works.